# custom c# item teplates

Tags: c#, templates, datetime

I wanted to make a template which would be affected by `DateTime.Now` or something similar.

For example, on 2015-08-07 at 12:45, if I click "add Foo class" to project, then this should land in the new file:

```
    class Foo201508071245 : Foo
    {
         public string Boo201508071245 { get; set }
    }
```

Is this achievable?

Comment: Yes, this is achievable. To answer this question would require a very large answer. Generally that is not favorable on SO. Try adding some new information like what you have tried and a specific part that your are stuck on.

Comment: Assume i created template, how can i make it to change file name as i want to be called "Foo201508071245.cs"? Or if i choose this template it should suggest "Foo201508071245.cs"

Comment: Pass your file name generator that `DateTime` by using `DateTime.Now`

Comment: How? Where? Is this related to custom wizard ?

Comment: It depends on how you implement the code generation. Once again, this is an extremely broad question. If you need help with a specific situation state that.